# PATCH Django Rest Framework

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, restangular

How to update a single field using the PATCH verb on django rest framework utilizing restangular? I have a nested model that I need to update just one field when submiting a form.

Comment: show us some code. in restangular there is the `.patch()` method available on a restangularized object that makes a `PATCH` request. Have you checked the [documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)? this is a trivial question for which you might find an answer easily.

Comment: Thanks iulian, it was a misunderstanding of mine. I already resolved that issue.

Comment: you can answer your question if you find the solution